# Complex search and extendable query on two and more collections

Tags: node.js, performance, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am working on Node.js + mongodb application and my question related to design of my database and queries.  Firstly, describe my db structure. I have in my database two collections users and values. Document in users collection looks like this:

```
 {
        "_id" : 31450861,
        "first_name" : "Jon",
        "last_name" : "Doe",
        "sex" : 2,
        "bdate" : ISODate("1981-08-01T21:00:00Z"),
        "city" : {
                "id" : 282,
                "title" : "Minsk"
        },
        "country" : {
                "id" : 3,
                "title" : "Belarussia"
        },
        "photo_max" : "https://foto.ru/RnhOKp2YJE4.jpg",
        "relation" : 4,
        "interests" : "science",
        "music" : "pop",
        "lang" : "RU",
}
```

This collection filled with users data (language, birthday, etc).
Documents from collection values looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("548023e5c16f310c23b75075"),
    "userId" : "31450861", //reference to _id in users collection
    "group1" : {
        "value1" : 13,
        " value2" : 7,
        " value3" : 3,
        " value4" : 14,
        " value5" : 17
    },
    "group2" : {
        " value1" : 9,
        " value2" : 6,
        " value3" : 17,
        " value4" : 12,
        " value5" : 13
    }
```

So I need to make search for users on this database with lots of parameters from this two collection (their values (from collection values), sex, city, language etc.). I didn’t embed document values into users because I do a lot queries separately on them (but may be it’s anyway wrong design I need help on this). In future there will be more collections with similar structure like values (or at least there will be reference to userId), which I’ll have to include in search query, and I’ll need agility to extend my query on more collections. 
So I need to run complex query on this collections (I know there is no JOINs in mongodb, so I know I have to query twice or use mapreduce).

So far my thoughts on this issue (aren’t tested in code just thoughts).

I need to write search function which performs 2 queries (and more in future):

1. Find users with same values and getting their ids.

   var values = db.collection('values'); 
   var ids = values.find({ value1: 1,  value2: 2,  value3: 3 }, {userId: 1 } )   //then transform ids so it became array with userId
2. Then in this found set find users on some more parameters (sex, birthday, language, etc)

   var users = db.collection('users'); 
   users.find({ $and: [{ _id: { $in: ids } }, {sex: 2 }, {lang: “RU” } ] });

My questions are:
1.  Is it normal approach or I’ll end up with very slow performance and mess in code when adding new collections and queries?
2.  If is it normal, how to easily add one more query to one more collection?
Any help, any thoughts are welcome! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rhetorical question: Have you considered whether MongoDB is right for your application? There are tradeoffs associated with RDBMS vs. NoSQL; if you foresee a lot of relational / join type queries, you may want to explore switching to a relational database like PostgreSQL or MySQL. Of course that may not be the correct solution; just something to consider.

Comment: Of course I considered it, now there is no way to move to RDBMS

Comment: Not true, there is always a way. Take a look at [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) and [Rivers](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb)